# Como obter menor valor sem funcao de agregação - SQL

Tags: sql, query

Supondo uma tabela Estudante que tem como atributos(Id,Nome,idade). Como eu obtenho o nome do estudante com menor idade mas sem usar funcao de agregação(MIN)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT * FROM estudante WHERE NOT EXIST (SELECT * FROM Estudante est_aux WHERE estudante.idade > est_aux.idade);
```

Answer (score 0):

Você faria desta forma no SQL Server:

```
SELECT TOP 1 * FROM estudante ORDER BY idade
```

NO MySQL seria desta forma:

```
SELECT * from estudante ORDER BY idade LIMIT 1
```